# How to turn off Visual Studio 2015 Roslyn error highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

For Resharper we can selectively turn it on/off, but I could not find a way to turn off the built-in Visual Studio 2015 code highlights/suggestions.

The reason I want to do this is because I have quite a few left-join linqs and these queries messed up Visual Studio.

I am seeing lots of squiggles on my linqs and I prefer to turn them off.

Here is one of the error I am talking about.. I have no idea how to get rid of it.

> The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

[image: The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?']

**EDIT**

I have found a way to fix this from ScottGu's blog here: [The C# ?? null coalescing operator (and using it with LINQ)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq)

Comment: Do you mean IntelliSense or Syntax highlighting?

Comment: I mean the live red, yellow, green squiggles that highlights errors in the code.

Comment: @RosdiKasim: Use the lightbulb to add a `#pragma` to disable the warning.

Comment: It looks like the hint is actually right in this case. The property Id will always have a value here. Actual correct thing to check IsSelected in this case would be IsSelected = ps.Any()

Answer (score 8):

If you are talking about the Code Analysis rules. Then under the project references, there is an analyzers node.

[image: Visual Studio Analyzers Node]

If you right click and select "Open Active Rule Set", then you can turn off any of the analyzers you don't want.

Comment: I think this is it, but I still could not find the one that relates to my scenario. Btw I have found a way to fix this from ScottGu's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq

Comment: @RosdiKasim it would have been useful if you had posted the correct link or an answer to your own question that describes how you solved your problem

Comment: Is there any way to store all personal Code Analysis rules changes in "This computer" scope rather than in solution folder? Just like ReSharper offers this possibility for its settings.

Comment: Not available anymore in .Net Core libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `((int?)result.Id).HasValue`? This is the correct way to check a nullable type for nul value.