# How do I remove Roslyn?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, codelens

I'm in Visual Studio 2015 and Roslyn just isn't working. The documentation within Visual Studio for Roslyn is non existent and as I'm perfectly happy with resharper at this time I'd like to get Roslyn out of my hair. How to do this?

Comment: Roslyn is the compiler so it seems unlikely removing it will accomplish what you wish. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: If you mean disable / remove the "light bulb" (analyzers) the answer to that is over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353155/how-to-turn-off-visual-studio-2015-rc-roslyn-error-highlighting

Comment: Resharper is gradually working and merging into Roslyn, so?

Comment: "Roslyn just isn't working". In what way?

Comment: Above each method there is a grey string saying "- references". When I hover on this string the tool tip says "loading references for this method. (Alt+2)". Presumably Visual Studio is running some never ending task, I want it to stop trying to help me in this way in the hope it speeds up the ide. A colleague who is in love with Visual Studio as an ide suggested it is a Roslyn thing.

Comment: That feature is called "CodeLens". You can [turn it off as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457796/how-to-turn-off-codelens-references).

Comment: I presume that you have installed Roslyn using NuGet. So, you can uninstall it there. Do have in mind that you will need to uninstall a number of other packages as well before that. On the other hand, you can remove package.config from project and delete appropriate references form project too.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off this feature in Tools/Options/Text Editor/All Languages/CodeLens. But I would instead try to understand what and why isn't it working for you and report it to Microsoft. It's a useful feature of VS2015.